# Its possible to create vertical menu for Liferay Themes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay

I started to learn Liferay themes.
I see many themes but each with a horizontal menu like in Classic Theme.
But I want a vertical menu. Is it possible using bootstrap to do it?
Or Liferay can use only horizontal menu?
If its possible where can I read about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liferay themes are defined using velocity or freemarker template.
You can defined vertical menu in your page by modifying these templates.
You can take a look at `navigation.vm` (of unstyled-theme) which contains the html code to show the page-navigation menu.

Also you can take a look at the [`portal_normal.vm`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/portal_normal.vm) which actually includes the [`navigation.vm`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/navigation.vm) and all the other `CSS` and `JS` files which would be necessary.

By default liferay uses horizontal navigation but with adequate changes in the CSS through themes you can achieve Vertical menu.

Other option is:

1. Create a Theme without menu on top
2. Create a page with a side column.
3. Adding "navigation portlet" on your column